# upgrading vaadin to version 23.3.0 causes lombok to stop working

Tags: vaadin, upgrade, lombok

When I upgraded the vaadin version from 23.0.2 to 23.3.0, I get an error "cannot find symbol". This symbol is generated by lombok, so i think that for some reason lombok has stopped working. Except for the vaadin version change the pom remains unchanged. So I expect everything should work. The error I get is the following:

[ERROR] /C:/bosa/workspaces/gdpr-frontend/src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/vaadin/component/translation/I18NConditional.java:[38,60] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getParameters()

This symbol is generated by Lombok:

```
@Getter
@ToString
public class I18NConditional implements Translatable {

private String defaultValue;
private Map<String, Predicate<Object[]>> predicatesByValue;
private Object[] parameters;

@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Set<LocaleChangeManager> observers;

public I18NConditional() {
}

public I18NConditional(String key, Object... parameters) {
    defaultValue(key).parameters(parameters);
}

public String getValue() {
    if (this.predicatesByValue != null) {
        Optional<Map.Entry<String, Predicate<Object[]>>> optEntry = this.predicatesByValue.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().test(getParameters()))
                .findFirst();

        if (optEntry.isPresent()) {
            return optEntry.get().getKey();
        }
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
}
```

The pom.xml is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>be.bosa.digital.assets</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdpr-frontend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.56-29ab144</version>
    <name>gdpr-frontend</name>
    <description>Digital Assets GDPR Frontend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.3.0</vaadin.version>
        <mockwebserver.version>4.9.1</mockwebserver.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.7</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <vaadin.gatanaso.version>4.0.0-rc2</vaadin.gatanaso.version>
        <karibu.testing.version>1.3.11</karibu.testing.version>
        <security.environment>demo</security.environment>
        <sonar.exclusions>
            src/main/java/be/bosa/eloket/**/*,
            src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/vaadin/component/**/*,
            src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/security/control/**/*,
            src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/consultperson/**/*,
            src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/healthindicator/**/*,
            src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/ui/*,
            src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/ui/**,
            src/main/java/be/bosa/digital/assets/gdpr/frontend/ui/**/*
        </sonar.exclusions>
        <cxf.version>3.4.2</cxf.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-ecosystem-snapshot</id>
            <url>https://devops.digital.belgium.be/nexus/repository/maven-ecosystem-snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons.componentfactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>masked-text-field</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.gatanaso</groupId>
            <artifactId>multiselect-combo-box-flow</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.gatanaso.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.olli</groupId>
            <artifactId>clipboardhelper</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-charts-flow</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-grid-pro-flow</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-confirm-dialog-flow</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Jackson dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.69</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${mockwebserver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>${mockwebserver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mvysny.kaributesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>karibu-testing-v10-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${karibu.testing.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--BOSA FSB Security configuration, needed when running from within IntelliJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be.bosa</groupId>
            <artifactId>eloket-security-${security.environment}</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/resources/lib/eloket-security-${security.environment}.jar
            </systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>gdpr-frontend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                            <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <defaultOptions>
                                <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
                            </defaultOptions>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/AttributeQuery/CPS_AttributeQueryService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/AttributeQuery/CPS_AttributeQueryService.wsdl
                                    </wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/ConsultKbo/CPS_WSConsultKBOService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/ConsultKbo/CPS_WSConsultKBOService.wsdl
                                    </wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/ConsultKbo/CPS_WSConsultAgentEnterprise.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/ConsultKbo/CPS_WSConsultAgentEnterprise.wsdl
                                    </wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/GetPerson/CPS_wsPersonGetService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/GetPerson/CPS_wsPersonGetService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-ecosystem-release</id>
            <url>https://devops.digital.belgium.be/nexus/repository/maven-ecosystem</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-ecosystem-snapshot</id>
            <url>https://devops.digital.belgium.be/nexus/repository/maven-ecosystem-snapshot</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please describe why you think Vaadin is the culprit here. Vaadin has nothing to do with your Lombok generated code and works from V6-V24 flawlessly.

Comment: The only thing that I change is upgrade the vaadin version. There is no other thing that changes. Vaadidn works for me for version 23.0.2. This error is generated when I upgrade the vaadin version to 23.3.0. If i revert back to version 23.0.2, my project compiles. If I change it to version 23.3.0, my code does not compile.

Comment: What lombok version are you using? Using 23.3.0 pulls different dependencies, perhaps there is some dependency problem there?